# Using local storage to add user inputted rows permanently on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, local-storage

I am creating a website that takes two inputs a topic and a link and it appends them as a row to the HTML table. On clicking a '+' button it must do the needful. I wanted to use local storage so as to store these links and topics on the page permanently. Since I am new to the concept on local storage, any type of help would be appreciated.

This is my code snippet:

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table');
let topicInput = document.querySelector('#topic');
let linkInput = document.querySelector('#link');

function getTopic () {
    return localStorage.getItem("mytopic");
}

function getLink () {
    return localStorage.getItem("mylink");
}

function updatePage () {
    let topic = topicInput.value;
    let link = linkInput.value;
    let template = `
    <tr>
        <td>${topic}</td>
        <td>${link}</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="buttonDelete" value="-" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
    </tr>`;
    table.innerHTML += template;
}

function addFunction () {
    var rTopic = document.getElementbyId("topic").value;
    var rLink = document.getElementbyId("link").value;

    localStorage.setItem("mytopic", rTopic);
    localStorage.setItem("mylink", rLink);

    updatePage();
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="topic" placeholder="Add topic" size="50">
<input type="text" id="link" placeholder="Add link" size="50">
<button id="buttonAdd" onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
```

Comment: I don't think that you can use JavaScript or HTML to access local storage. You should use AJAX (thats js sending data to backend) and then backend program (php, deno...) to fetch some data that you can display (through js) in HTML. Is this helpful?

Comment: And in what way does your code not work as expected?  Are you getting an error on the browser's console?

Comment: @JonNezbit: [JavaScript can indeed be used to access `localStorage`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @David I think what he meant is local storage as a file on server, but maybe I am wrong about that

Comment: FYI: localStorage is not permanent and limited in space.

Comment: You need to store an array of items to the storage. You are storing a single item and keep overwriting it.

Comment: You misspeled this -> `getElementbyId`, it should be  `getElementById` (its the word `By`)

Comment: @JonNezbit If it was on the server, it'd be called `remoteStorage` 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is you would need to store a stringified array into local storage and parse it back out when the page loads. You append to the array when you add new rows.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table tbody');
const topicInput = document.querySelector('#topic');
const linkInput = document.querySelector('#link');

// grab the records from local storage.
const records = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data") || '[]');
const rowIndex = 0;

function addRecord(topic, link) {
  const template = `
        <tr>
            <td>${topic}</td>
            <td>${link}</td>
            <td><input type="button" class="buttonDelete" value="-"></td>
        </tr>`;
  table.innerHTML += template;
}

function addFunction() {
  const rTopic = document.getElementById("topic").value;
  const rLink = document.getElementById("link").value;
  // add to the array
  records.push({
    topic: rTopic,
    link: rLink
  });
  updateLocalStorage();
  addRecord(rTopic, rLink);
};

function updateLocalStorage() {
  // save updated records array
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(records));
}

table.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  const delButton = evt.target.closest(".buttonDelete");
  if (delButton) {
     const row = delButton.closest("tr");
     const index = Array.from(row.parentNode.children).indexOf(row);
     records.splice(index, 1);
     row.remove();
     updateLocalStorage();
  }
})

// loop over the records in localstorage.
records.forEach(function(record) {
  addRecord(record.topic, record.link);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="topic" placeholder="Add topic" size="50">
<input type="text" id="link" placeholder="Add link" size="50">
<button id="buttonAdd" onclick="addFunction()">+</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And as I stated before, localstorage is not permanent. It can be easily cleared and it is also limited to the amount of data it can store.

Comment: This worked thank you! Can you help me write the program for updating local storage to removeItem when we press the delete button.